# Update value in nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary like this. Length may vary:

```
dct: dict = {'first': {'val1': {'subval1': 1, 'subval2': 555}, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}, 'second': {'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}}
```

I have a "path" to a value and a new content for that value:

```
path = ['first', 'val1', 'subval1', 1000]
```

How can I change the value in the dictionary? The "path" can change, the values ​​in it too. It could be:

```
path = ['third', 'firstval', 'val3', 'subval2', 999]
```

or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a recursive function to create dictionaries from your paths and then `update` your initial dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'first': {'val1': {'subval1': 1, 'subval2': 555}, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}, 'second': {'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}}

update_path = ['first', 'val1', 'subval1', 1000]

def create_dict_from_path(l):
    if len(l) > 1:
        return {l[0]: create_dict_from_path(l[1:])}
    else:
        return l[0]

update_dict = create_dict_from_path(update_path)
my_dict.update(update_dict)

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'first': {'val1': {'subval1': 1000}}, 'second': {'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}}
```

Edit: if you want to go until the deepest level of your dictionary in order to keep all key/value pairs, the recursive function will be a bit more intricated:

```
def update_dict_from_path(d, l):
    if len(l) > 2 and l[0] in d:
        update_dict_from_path(d[l[0]], l[1:])
    elif len(l) == 2 and l[0] in d:
        d[l[0]] =  l[1]

update_dict_from_path(my_dict, update_path)
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'first': {'val1': {'subval1': 1000, 'subval2': 555}, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}, 'second': {'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}}
```

Edit2: you might wanna check if you're not overwriting nested dictionaries with scalar values in case the same key is found at different levels: `elif len(l) == 2 and l[0] in d and not isinstance(d[l[0]], dict):`

Comment: This is very close, but this approach will remove 'subval2': 555. My difficulty is that only one variable in the dictionary should change. All others must remain where they are.